# Spherical polar co-ordinates in momentum space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems, fourier-transform, commutator

I'm trying to write this unequal time commutator in spherical polar coordinate, and align the polar axis to be along the direction of x:
$$
\large \Delta(x) = [\phi(x),\phi(0)] = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_p}(e^{-ipx}-e^{ipx})
$$
I was told that the first step is to rewrite the above integral as
$$
\large \Delta(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^{\infty}d\rho\ \rho^2\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{-1}^{1} d(\cos\theta)\frac{1}{2E(\rho)}(e^{-iE(\rho)t+i\rho|x|\cos\theta}-e^{iE(\rho)t-i\rho|x|\cos\theta})
$$
Where we denote $\rho = |p|$, and $E_p$ is transformed to $E{(\rho)}$.

From the definition of spherical coordinate in physics convention, we have $\theta\in[0,\pi]$. It makes sense to me the last integrand goes from -1 to 1, but I don't quite understand why do we have the factor of $\cos\theta$ (and integrate along that)? If we look at the spherical coordinate diagram, isn't $\cos\theta$ projecting the vector to the z-axis? Is that consistent with 'align the polar axis to be along the direction of x'?

And why are we interested in writing this commutator in spherical coordinate?

Comment: The normal spherical measure includes a $\sin\theta~d\theta$, where $\theta$ goes between 0 and $\pi$. You can make the change of variables to $u=\cos\theta$ so that $\theta$ goes between 1 and $-1$. The $-d(\cos\theta)$ is just another way of writing $du$ (because $du = d(\cos\theta) = -\sin\theta d\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the definition of spherical coordinate in physics convention, we have θ∈[0,π]. It makes sense to me the last integrand goes from -1 to 1, but I don't quite understand why do we have the factor of cosθ (and integrate along that)?

The usual measure is
$$
d\rho \rho^2 d\theta \sin(\theta) d\phi\;,
$$
where $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $\pi$.

Note that:
$$
\frac{d(\cos (\theta))}{d\theta} = -\sin(\theta)\;,
$$
Or, rather:
$$
d(\cos (\theta)) = d\theta\sin(\theta)
$$

So, when you change variables of integration from $\theta$ to $z = \cos(\theta)$, you just get a factor of
$$
dz
$$
in the integration since you already have $d\theta \sin(\theta)$ explicitly as part of the measure.

I'm using $z$ instead of $\cos(\theta)$ because it is helpful to think of it all as one single thing. In these terms, your integral reads:
$$
\large \Delta(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^{\infty}d\rho\ \rho^2\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{-1}^{1} dz\frac{1}{2E(\rho)}(e^{-iE(\rho)t+i\rho|x|z}-e^{iE(\rho)t-i\rho|x|z})
$$

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Could you explain a bit about why we get $i\rho|x|z$ on the exponential? I know it should correspond to the spatial components of the 4-vector, but I'm a bit confused about how it's related to the direction of x.

Comment: Because $\vec p$ and $\vec x$ are independent vectors, you can take $\vec x$ as pointing in a fixed direction in the $\vec p$ integration (in other words, $\vec x$ doesn't care that you are integrating over $\vec p$). Furthermore, you can, without loss of generality, take $\vec x$ to be pointing in the direction of $\hat p_z$ (the z-direction in p-space. Therefore, $\vec p \cdot \vec x = |p||x|\cos(\theta_p) = |p||x|z$. (Note, by the way, it is a little unfortunately that I chose the symbol $z$ for the change of variables variable, I did not mean to imply it is the $z$ component of $\vec x$).

Comment: Also, the $|x|$ in the equation you wrote is the magnitude of $\vec x$ not the four-vector. This is also confusing notation (but not my fault this time). I probably would have written it as $|\vec x|$ not $x$. The four-vector is $(ct, \vec x)$.

Comment: Many thanks!!! I this case can I just understand $\rho$ as $|\vec{p}|$?

Comment: Yes, $\rho$ here equals $|\vec p|$.